# MySQL within R filtering oldest date with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, r, date, filter

I have a table within a SQL database that I want to retrieve within R. But within the code that I use to retrieve it from the database, I want to do some filtering first in a SQL query.

Example data. When:

```
library(RMySQL)
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user=***, password=***, dbname=***, host='127.0.0.1')
log = dbGetQuery(mydb, "select * FROM log_item;)
```

Then I get a similar dataframe like:

```
firmwareVersion <- c("fw3","fw4","fw4","fw5","fw5")
date_created <- c("2015-09-01 21:04:10","2015-09-04 07:13:10","2015-10-03 15:23:09","2015-10-05 22:31:58","2015-10-06 23:34:03")
type <- c("type1","type1","type1","type2","type2")

log <- data.frame(firmwareVersion,date_created,type)
```

I want for each `type` only the `firmwareVersion` with the oldest date. 
So my result should be:

```
type1 || 2015-09-01 21:04:10 || fw3
type1 || 2015-09-04 07:13:10 || fw4
type2 || 2015-10-05 22:31:58 || fw5
```

I tried:

```
logDateMin = dbGetQuery(mydb, "select min(log_item.date_created) 
FROM log_item group by type,firmwareVersion;")
```

When I try it in R, it never finish the query and keeps "calculating". I think the date is a character string and not a date, but I don't now how to convert it (I looked it up, but can't find a proper solution). Also without the "min(log_item.date_created)" but with the "group by" it never finish. Without both it gives an instant result.

I know I can do this with ease in R and dplyr, but I have so much data that I think it is better to do this within the SQL code. There are a lot of duplicated firmware verions and I only need the oldest.

I hope my information is detailed enough and hopefully someone can help me with this.

With kind regards,

Robin

---

EDIT for SERBAN

```
firmwareVersion                  type     date_created
1.4.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type1 || 2015-09-26 13:43:55
1.4.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type1 || 2015-09-27 12:56:00
1.5.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type1 || 2015-09-28 12:19:28
1.4.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type2 || 2015-09-29 05:08:48
1.6.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type2 || 2015-09-29 11:43:19
1.6.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type2 || 2015-09-29 17:32:28
1.4.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type3 || 2015-09-29 17:37:36  
1.5.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type3 || 2015-09-29 17:38:55
1.6.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type4 || 2015-09-29 17:47:12
1.6.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type4 || 2015-09-29 17:54:08
```

outcome needed:

```
1.4.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type1 || 2015-09-26 13:43:55
1.5.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type1 || 2015-09-28 12:19:28
1.4.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type2 || 2015-09-29 05:08:48
1.6.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type2 || 2015-09-29 11:43:19
1.4.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type3 || 2015-09-29 17:37:36  
1.5.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type3 || 2015-09-29 17:38:55
1.6.20@91347 128d491347 128d4 || type4 || 2015-09-29 17:47:12
```

Comment: May I ask my there is more than one of "type1" "type2", etc?

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Because these are notifications that are send to the database when something change or after a specific time. There are other columns, but I removed them because they are of no interest. So there are a lot of duplicated values and I want to delete all of them and keep the oldest date.

Comment: Well, if the date_created is indeed varchar, you can try  using `STR_TO_DATE(date_created, '%Y-%c-%e %H:%m:%s)`

Answer (score 0):

You never specified the type of SQL database you're going against. Try this query:

```
SELECT
 type
 ,date_created
 ,firmwareVersion
FROM log_item
WHERE date_created = min(date_created)
ORDER BY type,firmwareVersion
```

Some databases might complain about the `min()` in a where clause. So in that case you'd use a nested select.

```
SELECT
type
,date_created
,firmwareVersion
FROM (
SELECT
 type
 ,date_created
 ,firmwareVersion
 ,min(date_created) as min_date
FROM log_item)
WHERE date_created = min_date
ORDER BY type,firmwareVersion
```

Comment: The poster did specify MySQL.

Comment: Thank you Serban for the post. It is not working so far though. Just to give a headsup: I use Rstudio (R) to get the data with the library RMySQL so i can write the query in MySQL (like Grothendieck said). I edited my question, thanks for specifying that.

Comment: @RobinvG can you do a select * from log_item limit 10 and dput it into the question?

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Done. Hopefully this is what you ment :)